# Lipschitz condition normed vector space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Am I right that $g: C^{1}[0,2],||*||_{C^1[0,2]} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(f)=f'(1)$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition?

Cause $|f'(1)-h'(1)|=|g(f)-g(h)|\le \text{max} |f-h|+ \text{max} |f'-h'|$, as the last term here contains already the lipschitz condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right: $$|g(f) - g(h)| = |f'(1) - h'(1)| \le \max_{[0,2]}|f'(x) - h'(x)| \le$$
$$\le \max_{[0,2]}|f'(x) - h'(x)| + \max_{[0,2]}|f(x) - h(x)| = \|f - g\|_{C^1},$$
then it is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $L = 1$.